# how to limit and display tag?

Tags: posts, tags, array, template-tags

Hi i need to show random 3 tags for a post. all my posts have been tagged with more than 10 tags, i need to display any 3 tags randomly.

for eg:

A sample post

```
<a href="/tag1">Tag1</a>
<a href="/tag2">Tag2</a>
<a href="/tag3">Tag3</a>
```

I am currently using `<?PHP the_tags()?>` to generate all tags how to restrict it to 3 randomly generated tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $posttags = get_the_tags();
   $count=0;
   if ($posttags) {
       foreach($posttags as $tag) {
          $count++;
          echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a> ';
          if( $count >4 ) break;
       }
   }
```

Comment: spot on ,i need to make it random. bcoz every time it shows first three tag(in ascending ord ). how to make it random?

Comment: just add shuffle($posttags); before $count=0;

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'hide_empty' => true,
) );

foreach($terms as $term) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
    $count++;
    <a href="echo $term_link" class="size-1"> echo $term->name </a>;
    if ( $count >36 )
        break;
}
```