# Get X post tags

Tags: tags

How to properly get only e.g. 3 post tags? My current code:

```
$post_tags = get_the_tags();
if (!empty($post_tags)) {
    foreach ($post_tags as $tag) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems similar to this one:
[how to limit and display tag?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26112/how-to-limit-and-display-tag)

Based on it you can use this code to limit the tags:

```
$post_tags = get_the_tags();
   shuffle($post_tags); // use this incase you want to pick the tags randomly
   $count = 0;
   if ($post_tags) {
       foreach($post_tags as $tag) {
          $count++;
          echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a> ';
          if( $count > 4 ) break;
       }
   }
```

It will return 3 tags only.

Comment: It works! That code return 5 tags. I changed 4 to 2 and now correctly return 3 tags. Thanks!